# Add onclick event into the html elements in wysiwyg editor

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, editor, wysiwyg, wysihtml5

I am using bootstrap-wysihtml5 editor. And I want to add onclick event for all the input elements.
I was trying to add the script into the iframe. this is not working
Is there any easy way to include the click event into the editor?

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue by adding "focus" and "blur" events of the editor.

Answer (score 0):

Note that it is possible to set default event handlers for elements by adding a custom parser rule and attach it to the editor's constructor.

Simple example:

```
<div id="toolbar" style="display: none;">
  <a data-wysihtml5-action="change_view">switch to html view</a>
</div>
<textarea id="textarea" placeholder="Enter text ..."></textarea>

<script src="../parser_rules/simple.js"></script>
<script src="../dist/wysihtml5-0.4.0pre.js"></script>
<script>
  wysihtml5ParserRules.tags.button = {
    set_attributes: {
        onclick: "console.log('You clicked a button.')"
    }
  }

  var editor = new wysihtml5.Editor("textarea", {
    parserRules:    wysihtml5ParserRules
  });
</script>
```